# Oracle Query in full table scan

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-execution-plan

I don't understand why this (partioned by range) table is in full table scan in this query:

```
UPDATE customer_table
   SET username = '',
       phone = '',
       ip = '',
       cell = '',
       channel = ''
 WHERE id = '';
```

I've also created this index:

```
CREATE INDEX customer_table_UPD_EXT_SYS ON customer_table
(USERNAME, CLI, IP, MSISDN, CANALE, TN)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need more information.  If, for instance, the `customer_table` is very small, then a full table scan is the most efficient way to implement the query.  Also, if `id` is a string, then `id = ''` will never evaluate to true in Oracle because the empty string is treated as `NULL` (by default).

Comment: Hi,
this table will contains about 1 million of records in every partition, so the full table scan must be avoid. In the query I've inserted the values '', but in the real query they'll be valorized

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the full table scan, the index must (at least partially) match the `WHERE` clause. In your example, a index on `customer_table.id` would help. Your index `customer_table_UPD_EXT_SYS` contains the updated columns; regarding your `UPDATE` statement, this is actually bad news since the index needs to be updated, too, which can be more expensive than updating the table.

Comment: I've also the index on id:

CREATE INDEX customer_table_TN ON customer_table (ID)

So, do you suggest me to delete the index on the update statement (not where condition)?

Comment: If you don't need it for other queries, drop it. That said, `where id = ''` is a completely pointless `where` clause in Oracle, since in Oracle, the empty string is null. To select rows with an empty `id`, there where clause must be `where id is null`. Unfortunately, this `where` clause won't use the `customer_table_TN index` either. See http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/null/index how this can be solved.